# grouping files by size with powershell

Tags: powershell

i have a directory and want to group (copy them somewhere) them (in three groups) by size

given:

```
c:\temp\dir

a.txt 200kb
b.txt 220kb
c.txt 230kb
d.txt 250kb
e.txt 270kb
f.txt 280kb
g.txt 290kb
h.txt 310kb
```

i list these files and put them in three seperate groups by simply iterating them (right now i just print output, but lets keep things simply):

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\dir\*.*
$count = 0;
foreach( $file in $dir)
{
    if ($count -eq 0)
    {
        write-output "1) $file"
    }

    if ($count -eq 1)
    {
        write-output "2) $file"
    }

    if ($count -eq 2)
    {
        write-output "3) $file"
    }

    $count = $count + 1

    if ($count -gt 2){
        $count = 0
    }

}
```

my question is: how can i sort the list by file size?
 is there a way to tell `$dir = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\dir\*.*` to be ordered by file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\dir\*.* | Sort-Object -Property Length
```

If you want the largest first:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\dir\*.* | Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Sort-Object` to sort based on a property:

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\dir\*.* | Sort-Object -Property "Length"
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to display filename + size, ordered by size (which I understand is the output your wish), you may also use select and format table...

```
$source="c:\temp\"
set-location $source
cls
$source_regex = [regex]::escape($source)
Get-ChildItem $source -recurse | where {-not ($_.psiscontainer)} | `
select fullname, Length | Sort-Object -Property Length | ft -wrap
```

The output will be :

```
C:\temp\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll                 659120
C:\temp\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll                 945288
```

...

Hope this helps
Best regards
Stéphane